# How to run Bin/Setup on spree commerce setup

Tags: deployment, e-commerce, spree, setup-deployment

I am setting up spree. Got far as this and dont know what to do thereafter. "Run bin/setup in said directory"
What must I type in the terminal to setup?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I'm trying to install spree commerce. Step 4 says that I need to "Run bin/setup in the said directory". I am using wsl command line. I don't know how to get past run this or what to type in the command line

Answer (score -1):

in terminal type bin/setup then press enter.
it will take about 5 minutes to install dependencies
bin/setup